# SQL error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

if you please help me i am having a problem in sql code asp.net C#.

my error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Incorrect syntax near ')'.

and my query code goes as follows:

```
string query = @"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails) 
                             values(" + 0 + "," + ListBox4.SelectedValue +"," + ListBox1.SelectedValue + "," + null + ")";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't insert `null` like that way. Use parameterized query.

```
string query = "insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails)
                values (@overall_rating,@paper_id,@conference_role_id,@details)";

cmd=new SqlCommand(query,cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@overall_rating",0);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithVaule("@paper_id",ListBox2.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conference_role_id",Listbox1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details",DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: +1 for parametrized query since that is safer from SQL Injection attacks, right?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as everybody else said already, you can't use null the way you are doing it but there are more serious issues than that:

1. Your sql statement is prone to SQL Injection attacks because you are not parametrizing your query
2. If you are not inserting a value into a column, simply don't list the column! This will work:

   `string query = @"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID)`
   `values(" + 0 + "," + ListBox4.SelectedValue +"," + ListBox1.SelectedValue +")";`

Answer (score 1):

I think the `null` is probably making things angry:

```
string query = @"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails) 
                   values(0," + ListBox4.SelectedValue +"," + ListBox1.SelectedValue + ",null)";
```

You'll notice I made your `0` part of the string and made the `null` part of the string (instead of concatenating integer `0` and a `NULL` value with the string)

Comment: @emilios, I believe jadarnel27 has it since the keyword null is understood by the INSERT statement and not the C# code you are writing.  Perhaps look at the value of query in the debugger or dump it to the screen to see the differences between yours and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with this example is you are creating a SQL string that you plan on sending to the Database that will be executed there. When you are making your string the result of the string is something like...

```
"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails) values(0, someValueFromListbox4,someOtherValueFromListbox1,)"
```

You will notice that the final parameter is missing. To fix this try this...

```
string query = @"insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails) 
                     values(" + 0 + "," + ListBox4.SelectedValue +"," + ListBox1.SelectedValue + ",NULL)";
```

Here is another example using string.format which I would reccommend

```
string query = String.format("Insert into ReviewPaper(Overall_Rating,Paper_ID,Conference_Role_ID,Deitails) Values(0,{0},{1},NULL)", ListBox4.SelectedValue, ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the null within the speech marks so the end looks like ",null)";